# UI-Bootstrap samples do not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

We are trying to work with UI-Bootstrap
http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

trying to work though the examples and nothing seems to be working. According to the documentation we only need to reference angular and bootstrap css. However, it also seems that we need to add a reference to ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js !?

Can someone please please shed some light on why the below isnt working, this is code directly off their website!:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="bootstrapDemoApp" id="top">
<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="script/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

</head>
<body ng-app>

<div ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl">


    <h4>Inline</h4>
<div style="display:inline-block; min-height:290px;">
  <div class="well well-sm" ng-model="dt">
      <datepicker min="minDate" show-weeks="showWeeks"></datepicker>
  </div>
</div>
</div>


<script>var DatepickerDemoCtrl = function ($scope) {
$scope.today = function() {
$scope.dt = new Date();
};
$scope.today();

  $scope.showWeeks = true;
  $scope.toggleWeeks = function () {
    $scope.showWeeks = ! $scope.showWeeks;
  };

  $scope.clear = function () {
    $scope.dt = null;
  };

  // Disable weekend selection
  $scope.disabled = function(date, mode) {
    return ( mode === 'day' && ( date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6 ) );
  };

  $scope.toggleMin = function() {
    $scope.minDate = ( $scope.minDate ) ? null : new Date();
  };
  $scope.toggleMin();

  $scope.open = function($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();

    $scope.opened = true;
  };

  $scope.dateOptions = {
    'year-format': "'yy'",
    'starting-day': 1
  };

  $scope.formats = ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'shortDate'];
  $scope.format = $scope.formats[0];
};

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are there any errors on the console ?

Comment: hi, yes, "Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]"

Comment: It means your app is missing the dependency module (bootstrap ui). Please see my answer.

Comment: Please note that in the markup above you have two ng-apps defined, one on the HTML tag and another on the BODY tag.

Comment: Thank you. was a miss type on my part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to inject 'ui.bootstrap' in your app.

Here is an example.

```
var app = angular.module('bootstrapDemoApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

UI Bootstrap is a separate Angular Module, you will have to inject it into you module:

so change your markup to:

```
<body ng-app="YourAppName">
```

and add this to the start of your script:

```
angular.module('YourAppName', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

and you will have to add your controller to your app:

```
angular.module('app').controller(DatepickerDemoCtrl);
```

Comment: hello how to use the angular bootstrap-ui in asp project

Comment: @Lijo same was as defined in my answer when defining your module. Just make sure you are including the necessary JS files before your JS files.

Comment: i have added the js but it still showing that ng controller attribute is invalid

Comment: Please create a new question and provide a link to it which has your code, and ideally a fiddle or plnkr